# Fluff over substance for CS degree?

Tags: computer-science

I can either get my CS degree from a college with a great name but horrible professors/curriculum or from a college with a lesser name but useful curriculum. Which would I more likely get a job with?

Comment: This has to do with Computer Science. It is a valid question.

Comment: Nope. For two reasons. 1) http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask 2) This site is not about Computer Science, which is **NOT** the same thing as programming. You should go to [Computer Science](http://cs.stackexchange.com/), a sister site of Stack Overflow, for questions like yours.

Comment: user2709365, career advice is off-topic here. But, come on, given the way you phrased the question, you've made up your mind.

Comment: Ok. Since there was a "computer-science" tag, I thought it would be relevant. You (Renan) could have pointed me to the sister site in the first place. Thanks.

Comment: Please see this as a friendly advice, not as a negative remark or something like that: if you've come here and couldn't figure out that your question was grossly off topic in a couple minutes or less (I'm assuming you have never lurked around here), then you might rethink your career choice. You're going to suffer a lot in CS. The course, I mean, and IRL, not the site.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about college degrees.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your skills are more important than the school. Go with the no-name.